# TableLayout of CodeName One

Tags: iphone, tablelayout, codenameone

I am trying to build a really simple  UI with **CodeName One**. I want a rectangular screen (to display image) and a button below it.
I can't find anything like a panel for the rectangular screen, so I just put a label.

The hierarchy is shown below:

- Container (TableLayout, 3 rows and 1 column)

The components inside the container are: container:

- Label (row=0, column=0, vertical span = 2)
- Button (row=2,column=0, vertical span=1)

Since vertical span of Label is 2, should not it occupy two rows? However, its visible height is same as 1 row. What is wrong?

What is the equivalent for panel (to show images) in this API?
 Is there a good tutorial for TableLayout managers?
I am familiar with JGoodies, can I use JGoodies with this API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gave an answer for this [here](http://www.codenameone.com/discussion-forum.html?place=msg/codenameone-discussions/kuzslJJWFfQ/5tFsS6izTQ4J)

Pasting here for completeness:

That's a really simple layout, you shouldn't use table layout for this at all.

For the single column just set the parent to BorderLayout and place a Label for the white panel in the center and the button at the south.

For the two column layout you can again use border layout, in the center place a component with a two column/one row grid layout. Place two labels for the panels.
Do the same for the south by placing a Container with a two column grid layout and two buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without specifying a vertical span of two. Specify a table with 2 rows, and it will expand the first row to fit the size of the image.